# Prometheus "negative" offset

Tags: prometheus, promql

I am trying to draw a a barchart in Grafana with a prometheus datasource.
My simple query looks as follows:

`max_over_time(energy_monitor_watthour_today[1d])`

I have Grafana set to the interval of 1d (This works fine, and gives me the highest point for each day). but using this, all of my results are exactly 1 day too far in the future. I would like to essentially give my results an offset that pushes them 1 day into the past.

I have tried using Prometheus's Offset function for queries:
`max_over_time(energy_monitor_watthour_today[1d] offset 1d)`

But this gives the exact opposite effect, and moves all my results 1 day into the future. using a negative offset like so:

`max_over_time(energy_monitor_watthour_today[1d] offset -1d)`

results in the following error:

> parse error at char 57: unexpected  in offset, expected duration

I have also tried to use Grafana's time shift feature, but this will just move my graph's timeframe, not change the actual date.

How can I move all the results of my query one day into the past?

Comment: This may be resolved with VictoriaMetrics, which supports negative offsets - see [MetricsQL docs](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/wiki/MetricsQL) for more details.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible to achieve with Prometheus. see: [github](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/pull/2673).
Switching to InfluxDB resolved the issue. Existing data can be migrated using [Prom2Influx](https://github.com/zhyon404/prom2influx).

**Edit**: This is possible with a newer version of Prometheus! [link](https://github.com/prometheus/prometheus/issues/6282)